# Using Waze maps API in Android

Tags: android, maps

Have anybody ever used Waze maps API on Android? Examples, useful links, step-by-step instructions will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

hi 
i think google map api is best for map dispaly on android
so u should go with google api

you should go with this way....

http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/mapkey.html

all the best:)

Comment: Thanks Sundaram. But we're already using Google maps in our app and we need to use Waze maps to provide a choise for user which maps to use.